# Create VM using Azure's java sdk tagging all related resources

Tags: java, azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-java-sdk

I'm trying to create a VM using Azure's Java ARM SDK (0.9.3) and I want to tag **all** of the related resources with a tag, so later on I can delete them by this tag (and I don't want to create a separate resource group for this VM and then delete it).

I have seen in the feedback forums here - https://feedback.azure.com/forums/216843-virtual-machines/suggestions/8945692-delete-vm-with-all-associated-resources that others are trying to do the same, but is there a way to tag all the related resources during creation time, rather that iterating all of them, because this will be the same as deleting them one by one.

In general - is there a better way for deleting all the resources without tags?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@s-rusev, It seems that the only way for deleting all the resources without tags is using Azure Resource Management REST API for template deployments to creating and deleting a VM. Please see the REST API reference [Template Deployments](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn790549.aspx) to know how to manage deployments of multiple resources.